# .net: Where is System.Design.NativeMethods?

Tags: .net

I'm finding references to this namespace but it is not actually in System.Design. If I add the line 
LOGFONT lf; 
to my code, the editors dropdown suggestions include:

System.Design.NativeMethods.LOGFONT

Do you know where to pick it up? I'm having trouble tracking it down. Is it some sort of a 3rd party add-on? It's not in the add references dialog list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly where you think it is. But as [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) show it's internal :

```
internal class NativeMethods
```

You could either access it by reflection (and add a dependency to the version of the framework as there is no guarantee on internal APIs) or write your own methods.

The easiest way as always for pinvoke is [Pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net), where you could find the [LOGFONT](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/LOGFONT.html) struct.

Comment: Yes you are both exactly right, I don't know what I was thinking. I was faked out by the dropdown box in the editor. It's showing internal classes you can't use.

Answer (score 0):

It is an `internal` class. It means, it's only accessible to classes defined inside that assembly.